# to use entity framework and Web api to execute a Patch operation

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

i have to use entity framework and Web api to execute a Patch operation with the partial values provided in request
I need to see it upodate his DB in patch operation
this code is not throwing any error but also not updating the DB
If i uncomment line " //_context.Entry(organization).State = EntityState.Modified;" , its breaks apart.
"Organizations" is a modal class and also the database table name

```
HttpPatch("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PatchOrganization(string id, Delta<Organization> organization)
{    
    try
    {
        var organizationFromDB = await _context.Organizations.FindAsync(id);
        if (organizationFromDB == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        _context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;


        organization.Patch(organizationFromDB);

        _context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        //_context.Entry(organization).State = EntityState.Modified;

        //_context.Organizations.DetectChanges();//

        //_context.Update(organizationFromDB);
        //_context.Entry(organizationFromDB).CurrentValues.SetValues(organization);
        //_context.Entry(organization).State = EntityState.Modified;
        //_context.Organizations.Entry().State = EntityState.Modified;


        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: i am using Odata to track changes. will need to add the associated nuget package

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Deltas;

Comment: *its breaks apart* -- That's very vague. Also, what happens in `organization.Patch`? And please only post the code you have a question about. Remove all irrelevant comments. In short, post a [mre].